# Time complexity of reachability problem in graph theory - O(n)?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Nielsen and Chuang's *Quantum Computing and Quantum Information*, page 144, ex. 3.29, poses the following problem: "determine whether there is a path between two specified vertices in a graph. Show that can be solved using O(n) operations if the graph has n vertices."

They represent a graph as a set of vertices and a set of edges (vertex pairs). I don't see how you can do this in linear time. It seems like you have to search the vertex list multiple times, potentially once for each vertex, giving $O(n^2)$

Comment: This might help: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23320/can-we-test-whether-two-vertices-are-connected-in-time-linear-in-the-number-of-n See also the errata for the book: https://michaelnielsen.org/qcqi/errata/errata/errata.html